# Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

So this is my first experience with AWS. I have a nodejs/typescript setup with source from github. It goes through 2 stages of the codepipeline

- **Build**: I use a `buildspec.yml` file to build the typescript file and dump it in an S3 bucket. Here's the content of the `buildspect.yml`.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - "npm install"
  build:
    commands:
      - "npm run build"
artifacts:
  files:
    - "dist*/*"
  discard-paths: yes
```

And my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "aws-install",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node ./dist/app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.35",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.0"
  }
}
```

- **Deploy**: The deploy stage is an Elastic Beanstalk thing. I believe it's suppose to take the output of the build and deploy to an EC2 instance. I don't think this is what's happening. It gives the following error.

[image]

---

**Here's how my general setup looks like**

[image: AWS Pipeline screenshot]

**Logs**
I download full logs and I spot a few more details about the error

\var\log\eb-engine.log

```
2021/03/24 10:05:10.373225 [ERROR] update processes [web nginx cfn-hup healthd] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory
2021/03/24 10:05:10.373235 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Track pids in healthd]. Stop running the command. Error: update processes [web nginx cfn-hup healthd] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/web.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/web.pid: no such file or directory
```

I really don't know what else to do here. Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log` for more detailed errors?

Comment: Nothing strange there. Do you want me to post what I have there?

Comment: Did you find a solution? i am facing same issue.

Comment: No, I didn't. I have since deployed the project on Heroku because I couldn't get through this.

Comment: I had a same problem. In my case, build says it is OK, like it was successful, but it was not. On some step i got nuget package build and publish and that was failing and build went on to the end saying it is successful where in reality it is not.

Comment: any news, i had the exactly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It's related to old versions used during your last deployment.
you should delete your application versions and restart the pipeline again.
if it didn't work delete the deployment environment and create it again.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, but i have found a way to solve it, you can try the steps i adopted and solve yours.

**this is the error response i got:**

- after the **source** succeeded
- and **build** succeeded
- **deploy** failed

i had to go to -> logs -> request logs -> last 100 lines, below is what i saw

[image]

i had to go to package.json on my project and remove some lines of code just like below.
[image]

then i have to replace it

[image]

when that is done, commit your code and push to your branch, go back to your pipeline and click on release change.

then go to your elastic beanstalk and click on actions -> rebuild environment